# Display the correct monthly amortization and remaining balance using PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I wrote a program which will display the customer monthly amortization and the remaining balance of customer's payment monthly amortization, example, If the customer has 5742 monthly amortization and he/she paid 10000, the system should display the 5742 and the remaining balance which is amounting 4258. Below is my code,

```
$remaining = 10000;
$amort = 5742;

for($remaining += $amort; $remaining > $amort; $remaining-=$amort) {

     $hi = ($remaining) < $amort ? $remaining  : $amort;
     echo $hi, "<br/>";
}
```

result:

```
5742
5742
```

Expected result should be:

```
5742
4258
```

Updated code, it works so well, but how do I insert an if else? let say, I wanted to insert it in database?

```
for($remaining += $amort; $remaining > $amort; ($hi = ($remaining-=$amort) < $amort ? $remaining  : $amort) . 

 print((($hi == $sales_mi) ? $hi . "<br/>" : $hi . "<br/>" ))

);
```

Comment: I don't know why you're doing this way, but look at @Raptor answer... change your `for` loop to `for(; $remaining >= 0; $remaining-=$amort)`

Comment: Hi @Berriel I update my code above, I have question, what if I wanted it to insert in database? how do I include an if else operator?

Comment: StackOverflow recommends you to open a new question if it is a new problem...

Answer (score 0):

In for loop, the first expression `$remaining += $amort` is executed once only, and it's rarely to use `+=` in the first expression. And the third expression is executed **after** each iteration.

Loop 1:

```
$remaining += $amort // $remaining = 15742
$remaining > $amort; // yes, $remaining is larger than $amort, continue
echo $hi // print out $amort ( 5742 ), since $remaining > $amort
$remaining -= $amort // $remaining = 10000
```

Loop 2:

```
$remaining > $amort; // yes, $remaining is still larger than $amort, continue
echo $hi // print out $amort ( 5742 ), since $remaining > $amort
$remaining -= $amort// $remaining = 4258
```

Loop 3:

```
$remaining > $amort; // no, stop the loop
```

Hope the above clear your myst.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: my problem now is how do i insert the display value in database? i update my code above. thanks

Comment: the whole question is not related to database. Please ask another question for this. Make sure you show what database you are using.